# grep how to suppress display of non-matched file?

Tags: grep, search, stdout, options

I am trying to find files containing a specific word using `grep`. There are many files in the directory (> 500)

#### Command I run

```
$ grep 'delete' *
```

#### Output

```
validate_data_stage1:0
validate_data_stage2:0
validate_data_stage3:0
validate_data_stage4:0
validate_data_stage5:0
validate_input_stage1:0
validate_input_stage2:0
validate_input_stage3:0
validate_input_stage4:0
.... and hundred of such lines
```

These are the files that don't contain the given match. I want to suppress those lines from displaying to stdout. I know of `-q` switch, but that would suppress the complete output, which I don't want.

How do I do that?

Comment: Normally, `grep` should not print out file names of non-matching files. Actually, it looks like `grep` considers a line with the content `0` to be matching. Can you post the exact search pattern you are using?

Comment: The complete grep cmd I used was `grep 'delete' * -R`, but I don't think `-R` is causing any issue. And yes, it normally doesn't print the non-matching ones, but not sure what's the case here...

Comment: @step @everyone.. Strange... After seeing the edited post above. I tried `grep -- 'delete' *` (added `--`) and it worked as expected. Removing the `--` is leading to the above display.

Comment: @Stephane Indeed you are correct. I searched the dir... and there was a file with name `-ci`. Thanks for resolving the issue. You can post this scenario as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's the behavior exhibited by `grep -c`.

Probably you have a file whose name starts with `-` and contains a `c` character and you're using GNU grep without setting the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable.

Use:

```
grep -- delete *
```

or better:

```
grep delete ./*
```

`--` marks the end of options so that that filename will not be considered as an option (with a POSIX grep, it wouldn't since the non-option `delete` argument would have marked the end of options), but it wouldn't address the problem of a file called `-`. The `grep delete ./*` is more robust but has the drawback of outputting the extra `./` for matching files (though that may be considered a bonus since that helps identify file names that contain newline characters).

Answer (score 16):

Add

```
| grep -v ':0$'
```

Not very elegant but I think will do the job.

Adding `-l` to your command will give you only matches but it will also suppress printing number of matches for each file.

Comment: `-l` worked. the work-around is also good. Thanks

Comment: the grep line should be `grep -v ':0$'` so only those at the end of a line are matched (however, the `grep -l` approach is far better as long as you don't need line counts)

Answer (score 10):

Using `grep -l` you will only get the files that contain at least one match.

Do you need information about how many matches there are in a file at all? Because the you could skip using `-c` which is used to count the number of matches in a file.

edit: And like warlock said using `-I` to suppress matches in binary files could also be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

## How to grep nonzero counts:

`grep -rIcH 'string' . | grep -v ':0$'`

- `-r` Recurse subdirectories.
- `-I` Ignore binary files <sup>(thanks [@tongpu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56367/33543), warlock)</sup>.
- `-c` Show count of matches. Annoyingly, includes 0-count files.
- `-H` Show file name, even if only one file.
- `'string'` your string goes here.
- `.` Start from the current directory.
- `| -v ':0$'` Remove 0-count files. <sup>(thanks [@LaurentiuRoescu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56357/33543))</sup>

(I realize the OP was unintentionally -c counting, but google(grep nonzero count) lands here.)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Laurentiu's answer, you can also use the listing of `-l` as the file inputs for grep :
`grep -r "pattern" -c $(grep -rl "pattern")`
It allows keeping grep's coloring, but does the same thing in the background

Comment: note that filenames & directories that contain any whitespace or wildcards will be mistakenly split and matched as a result.